# Excel filling data down

Tags: excel

Is it possible to create rows of data that repeat the numbers from 1 to 1,029 every four rows? So the first four rows are 1, next four rows 2, and so on?

I have attempted to use a macro to do so, however, I haven't had any luck yet.

Similarly, I also need to repeat the values of 8,9,12, and 15 which correspond to the ages of these individuals. Is there a shorthand method for both?

Any help is greatly appreciated, and would save me a lot of time from manually filling in my excel sheet,

Thanks,

Oliver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **A1** enter:

```
=ROUNDUP(ROW()/4,0)
```

and copy downward.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this, is it a similar technique for the 8,9,12,15 fill also?

Comment: @OliverMitchell  to start at **8**, in **A1** enter:  `=ROUNDUP(ROW()/4,0)+7` .......................to change the repetition factor, just change the **4**

Comment: Cheers for this. I will actually need this to start at A2, as I need the column variable names in A1 for analysis in R. However, when I attempt to modify the formula to fill down, I always end up with three 1's, rather than four. The rest of the numbers in the sequence are fine though.

Comment: To start the sequence at an **arbitrary cell** begin with:  `=ROUNDUP(ROWS($1:1)/4,0)` rather than the equation in my Answer.

Comment: Perfect. I'm still struggling with the 8,9,12,15 sequence, could you assist?

Answer (score 1):

Use VBA

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Const endCount As Long = 1029
    Dim arr(), i As Long, rowCounter As Long
    ReDim arr(0 To (4 * endCount) - 1)

    For i = 0 To endCount - 1
        arr(rowCounter) = i + 1
        arr(rowCounter + 1) = i + 1
        arr(rowCounter + 2) = i + 1
        arr(rowCounter + 3) = i + 1
        rowCounter = rowCounter + 4
    Next i
    ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 1).Resize(UBound(arr) + 1, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arr)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am having an issue using VBA for this, as I haven't used it before. Are you able to provide a step-by-step tutorial for this?

Comment: 1) Open VBE with Alt + F11. 2) View project explorer 3) Right click in project explorer window and add standard code module (not class) 4) Paste code into the standard module 5) Hit the green run triangle at the top of the ribbon or press F5.

Comment: That's great thanks. Is there a way to repeat the sequence: 8,9,12,15 for the 1 to 1029 values repeated four times ?

Comment: So I would repeat the sequence 8,9,12,15 down to row number 4117, is this possible as doing it by keyboard is very time consuming

Comment: Honestly a life saver, I've had to sort the whole data set for use in R, and i'm nearly there in doing it and this will save so much time!

Comment: Hi again, is it possible to create the same code for repeating 1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5, etc, 1029,1029? Also, for 8,9,8,9,8,9 up to row 2058?

Comment: Hi, yes I have i'm just not too sure what to add and remove?

Comment: The public sub test is appearing in red

Comment: You can ask a new question and I can answer there. If you leave a comment here I will know when you have posted.